# Calling a JFrame method from another JFrame on Button Click

Tags: java, swing

I searched on stack overflow for the similar answers for my question, but neither of them helped me.

So my problem is the following:

I have a main JFrame called `Main_Window`, on which I have a JTable and a JButton. After clicking the Button another JFrame (`Update_Window`) opens from Which I can update the table. The Update_Window JFrame has two TextFields and a `SUBMIT`Button.

Briefly, I want to update my JTable in the `Main_Window` from the `Update_Window` JFrame. After I type something in the TextFields and Submit with the Button, the data should appear in the `Main_Window`'s JTable, but it is not working.

This is my `Main_Window` JFrame:

```
    private void updateBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Update_Window newWindow = new Update_Window();
        newWindow.setVisible(true);
        newWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);  
    }  

    public void putDataIntoTable(Integer data, int row, int col) {
        jTable1.setValueAt(data,row,col);
    }
```

This is my `Update_Window` JFrame:

```
    private void submitBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityTextField.getText());
        price = Integer.parseInt(priceTextField.getText());
        Main_Window mw = new Main_Window();
        mw.putDataIntoTable(price,3,2);
    }
```

I think my problem is here `Main_Window mw = new Main_Window();`, because this creates a new Instance and it doesn't add the data to the correct window, or something like that.

Comment: getter and setter, could include objects, classes, controllers. There is many different approaches you can use

Comment: Use a JDialog instead of a JFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The line `Main_Window mw = new Main_Window();` is definitely wrong.

Better solution is:

```
public class UpdateWindow extends JFrame {
    private final MainWindow mainWindow;
    public UpdateWindow(MainWindow mainWin) {
        mainWindow = mainWin;
    }
    private void submitBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityTextField.getText());
        price = Integer.parseInt(priceTextField.getText());
        mainWindow.putDataIntoTable(price,3,2);
    }     
}
```

Also you need to correct the call of constructor for `UpdateWindow`

```
private void updateBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    UpdateWindow newWindow = new UpdateWindow(this);
    newWindow.setVisible(true);
    newWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);  
}
```

Please note: I've corrected your class names as it proposed by Java naming convention. `Main_Window` -> `MainWindow`, `Update_Window` -> `UpdateWindow`.

When my suggestion don't solve your problems, please provide a [mcve] so we can better identify your problems.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. But I'm not quite sure why does this work, can you explain it a little bit?  What is the difference in your solution and in the `Main_Window mw = new Main_Window();`

Comment: @DerrickWorsten the difference is that in your solution 2 (or probably more than 2) objects of type Main_Window are used (one is visible, all another objects are not visible). And you refresh an invisible object (instances). But in mine solution only one object (instance) of this class is used (the visible of course).

Comment: Oh I see, I understand now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: May I have another question, but it differs from my earlier question. By any chancem do you know, how could I accoplish to keep the data in the JTable after Closing the main JFrame(when I close the whole app and I re-run it).

Comment: @DerrickWorsten There are many possiblities to do it: save in a database, store in a text file with CSV format (good for a single table), store in XML format, or use java serialization ability. Of course you must also provide reading of objects on application start-up. The most easy way for a beginner is serialization (IMHO).

Comment: Medvynskyyn Sorry for my late response. Thank you I think I will check out  IMHO.